# How to import a function into a script in Astro using TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, astrojs

I have a custom `jsonFetch(..)` function for performing PUT requests to my external backend, but for some reason, I can't import it inside the `<script>` tag

```
---

// Code related to the Astro backend

---

// HTML code

<script type="module">
   // Attempt 1
   import {jsonFetch} from "../../utils/json-fetch";
  
   // Attempt 2
   // const {jsonFetch} = await import("../../utils/json-fetch");
</script>

// Attempt 3
// <script src="../../utils/json-fetch.ts" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

All import attempts show this error in the browser:

> GET http://localhost:4321/utils/json-fetch net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

The error makes sense because the `json-fetch.ts` file is located inside the `src` folder rather than in the `public` folder.

I don't think this is the best practice, but if I move `json-fetch.ts` to the public folder, I get a syntax error when importing the script, maybe because it's a TypeScript file

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `type="module"`:

```
<script>
  import { jsonFetch } from "../../utils/json-fetch";
</script>
```

From [the docs](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/client-side-scripts/):

> Astro will not process your script tags in some situations. In particular, adding `type="module"` or any attribute other than src to a `<script>` tag will cause Astro to treat the tag as if it had an `is:inline` directive.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Comment: maybe something wrong in json-fetch.ts? basic principle works for me: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-bktowq?file=src%2Fpages%2Findex.astro

Comment: Actually using `<script define:vars={{myVariable}}>` is giving me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module". 

Sorry I didn't mention that in the question

Comment: I created a new question mentioning `define:vars=`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78244932/astro-i-cant-import-a-function-and-use-definevars-inside-a-script-simultaneo